# How to query the activerecord based on the enum status?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying implement a search/filter action on a model **Production** based on a column **status**. The column `status` is of integer type. Later for the purpose of readability I used enum datatype on `status` column as follows.

```
class Production < ApplicationRecord    
  enum status:{
    Preproduction:1,
    Postproduction: 2,
    Completed:3
  } 
end
```

Then I started to work on a search/filter functionality to fetch the record based on the status given by the user.

**productions_controller**

```
def filter
    if params[:filter]
      @productions = Production.where('productions.status like ?', "%#{params[:filter]}%")
    else
      @productions = Production.all
    end
  end
```

**view**

```
<%= form_tag [:filter, :productions], :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :filter, params[:filter] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Filter", :status => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Now I am able to query the record properly only if I enter the integer values like `1` `2` or `3` in the text field. When I enter the status like `Preproduction` like I assigned, I am not getting the result. I am getting a blank page. How can I fix this ? How can I make it to accept the string and query successfully ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this...

```
@productions = Production.where('productions.status like ?', "%#{Production.statuses[params[:filter]]}%")
```

Enums have a pluralized class method, so enum `status` in Production has a hash 
`Production.statuses` which looks like your status hash but with the symbols changed into strings.